# Team Synchronization - how change background color?

Tags: java, eclipse

java 8

Eclipse 2021-12

Here mode **Team Synchronization**

And compare to versions of file:

[image]

As you can see the different are words: **interface** and **abstract class**.

The background of this place of different is gray.

Is it possible to change this color? E.g. to yellow.

Comment: This is easy to find in the preferences, as there are only a few colors and fonts for _Text Compare_: the color is called _Edition color_.

Comment: @howlger "Window -> Preference -> General -> Appearance - Colors and Fonts -> Edition color " change to yellow. But it not help. Background color not change.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are saying. Depending on the data it might be also the _Outgoing change color_. A plugin can also define its own color (_Team Synchronization_ sounds like SVN for which there are two different plugins).

Comment: @howlger I found "Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Color and Fonts -> Text Compare -> Outgoing change color". Set desire color. And now background color is yellow :-)